# How to add a else command in php?

Tags: php, magento

I have an attribute called "Merchant_Name".

The following code will place the "Merchant_Name" Just below the product name in product page.

Now I need to add an else command to this code like this:

If Merchant_Name is there then it should be "By Merchant_Name" else "XXXXX".

Hope you get me...

```
<div class="Merchant_Name">
<?php
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
if ($merchant_name){?>By <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('merchant_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); } ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

You mean, with an `if/else`?

```
<div class="Merchant_Name">
<?php
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');

if ($merchant_name) { 
    echo "By " . $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('merchant_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
} else {
    echo "By XXXXX";
}
?>
```

Or maybe this would be cleaner:

```
<?php
if($_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name')) {
    $name = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('merchant_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
} else {
    $name = "XXXXX";
}
?>
<div class="Merchant_Name">By <?php echo $name ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple and it would be simpler if you didn't switch in and out of PHP so often:

```
<div class="Merchant_Name">
By 
<?php
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
if ($merchant_name){
    echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('merchant_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
} else {
    echo 'XXXXX';
} 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Jay, it's true, but Magento's templates do that a LOT - html / php madness (drives me crazy, personally)

Comment: Ah - yikes! I missed the Magento tag! Thanks for the heads up @cale_b

Comment: *Oops, seems like I broke a perfect number here Sam* @JayBlanchard grin

Comment: *Perfects are made to be broken Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: @JayBlanchard Curious why you'd post a nearly identical answer, a minute after I posted mine. It looks like you've been around for a while and should know better.

Comment: @SmartyCoder Jay isn't the kind of guy who copies from others. He has integrity and then some, believe me.

Comment: Well @SmartyCoder I was probably writing mine when you were writing yours. Mine is different in as much as I didn't bail in and out of PHP and stated that. This question would generate a lot of similarly coded answers as there aren't too many ways this could be done.

Comment: @JayBlanchard fair enough, just wondering. (I didn't bail in and out of php either)

Answer (score 1):

Once you start the php tag try to finish your task. Don't switch in and out again and again.

```
<div class="Merchant_Name">
By 
<?php
if ($_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name')){
    echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('merchant_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
} else {
    echo 'XXXXX';
} 
?>
</div>
```